# Refresh Integer in JPanel

Tags: java, int, counter

I have a counter in a JPanel in my java applet. I want the counter to update every time the int of the counter changes. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a method `changeCounter` that allows you to change the counter. In that method update the control in your `JPanel`.

The proper way to go about this would be data binding, but afaik that's still not in Java. There are plenty of libraries to do so, though.

Another option would be to implement it the usual way, i.e. Observer pattern, using listeners. [There is a tutorial for that, even](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). Generally it works that way in Swing. You have objects that themselves can fire property change events whenever one of their properties changes and you add listeners for those events to change control values accordingly (and vice versa when the user changes a value in a control).